# Is the PayPal shopping cart accepted?

Tags: javascript, html, paypal, shopping-cart

I'm working on a website for a customer on which I want to implement a shopping function. 
 I know that it's really easy to create a PayPal shopping cart,
but is this method accepted by web-developers world or should I look for other methods?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is accepted.

```
<a href="JavaScript: OpenPayPalWindow('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_cart&amp;business=businessemail&amp;item_name=' + escape('{$article->mArticle.name}') +'&amp;amount={$article->mArticle.price}&amp;add=1&amp;return=urlshopping&amp;currency_code=USD&amp;cancel_return=urlshopping')">
   Add to basket
</a>
```